# Node.js Installing Error "The Application is only supported on windows 8.1, windows server 2012 R2, or Higher"

Tags: node.js, user-interface, web

while i am trying to install Latest LTS Version: 14.15.3 (includes npm 6.14.9) from node.js i am getting given below error

System Information :
Windows 7 Ultimate

Error Information:
"The Application is only supported on windows 8.1, windows server 2012 R2, or Higher" error coming while trying to instaling on my windows 7 OS

[image]

Comment: Aside, you really shouldn't be running Windows 7 anymore unless you really know what you're doing - it was EOL'd in January 2020 and **no longer receives critical functionality or security patches**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/download/release/latest-v12.x/ download this version which is just older than 14th version of node v12 is work fine in windows 7

Answer (score 6):

Use a lower version of Node. Starting in Node v14.x versions Windows 8.1 or newer is required.

You should use v12.x since that’s the latest LTS that supported Windows 7. If you don’t care about LTS, v13.x also supported Windows 7.

https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/